# How to bulk insert with RedBeanPhp?

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I was hoping for an example on how to bulk insert new "beans" in readbeanphp without looping over each instance.

It shows an example creating and saving a beans here: http://redbeanphp.com/manual/create_a_bean

It makes mention of storeAll($beans) method, but I am unsure exactly how I am suppose to format the data in $beans.

I have tried googling for this and can not find anything related to bulk inserts. Maybe I have searched for the wrong terms.

I am new to this ORM, any help with would appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are definitely right on track.  Create a new bean using `$bean=R::dispense('bean');` or multiple beans as an array `$beans=R::dispense('bean',5);`

Then you populate the beans with data:

```
$bean->title='Hello World!';
//or with an array
$beans[0]->title='Hello World!';
$beans[1]->title='Hello World! Bean 1';
//etc
```

Then store the bean(s):

```
R::store($bean);
//or
R::storeAll($beans);
```

All the beans must be the same type if you have multiples as far as I know, so you can do something like:

```
$beans=array();
$beans[]=R::dispense('bean');
$beans[]=R::dispense('bean');
$beans[0]->title='Hello World!';
$beans[1]->title='Hello World!1';
R::storeAll($beans);
```

I could be wrong about that though.  The main thing is that this is all a typical ORM, but redbean also supports regular SQL if you need to use it.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Some real data behind this approach.
FIRST APPROACH.
foreach item found

```php
$bean = R::dispense('bean');
$bean->title = "hello";
R::store("bean");
```

time taken for 5660 rows = 43s on my mac

SECOND APPROACH.

```php
$beans=array();
$beans[]=R::dispense('bean');
$beans[]=R::dispense('bean');
$beans[0]->title='Hello World!';
$beans[1]->title='Hello World!1';
R::storeAll($beans);
```

For 5660 rows, 46s. The storeAll is where all the time is. So its taking ages to store these beans.

THIRD APPROACH

```php
$beans=R::dispense('bean',5560);
    
for loop
  $bean[$i]->title = "hello world";
end for
    
R::storeAll($beans);
```

For 5660 rows 45s.
Result. None of these approaches are any quicker. : (
RedBean Transactions didn't seem to make this any quicker either

From the creator of RedBean https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811996/445492 Bulk Insert is not supported, use pure sql.

FOURTH APPROACH

```php
for loop
  R::exec("insert into bean(title) values (1,'hello world')");
end for
```

for 5660 rows 7.3s <----- WOW
(please note: I am actually doing some stuff prior so all these results are -4.3 seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

Hence every bean needs to be created first and the method to create a bean is dispense

```
$bean = R::dispense('customers');
$bean->name = "John";
R::store($bean);
$bean->name = "Walter"
R::store($bean);
```

the code above creates only one bean even after storing it. Still $bean refers to the same object, so for each record you have to create a new been by using dispense method.

Luckily we have storeAll method that stores all the beans but it requires an array of beans. So we create a bean in each iteration and push it to the array and then at the end of loop we just pass that array to storeAll function.

```
//create empty array 
$beans = array();   

//for each customer post create a new bean as a row/record          
foreach ($post as $customer) {
     $bean = R::dispense('customers');
     //assign column values 
     $bean->firstName = $customer['first_name'];
     $bean->lastName = $customer['last_name'];
     //push row to array
     $beans[] = $bean;
 }

 //store the whole array of beans at once               
 R::storeAll($beans);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Bono, Description added

Answer (score 0):

In the approaches 1, 2 and 3 suggested by John Ballinger, one way to optimize the run time is to put all the insertions performed by storeAll($beans) inside one database transaction. This could be done as follows: replace the line "R::storeAll($beans)" by the following three lines:

```
R::begin();
R::storeAll($beans);
R::commit();
```

This approach reduces dramatically the run time when the array $beans is large, AND is not necessary to use SQL "explicitly".